# How to get rid of the value using a Gson TypeAdapter?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I have a json string that looks as follows:

```
{ "SomeStringProperty": { "value":"StringValue"},
  "SomeIntProperty": { "value": 1},
  "SomeBooleanProperty": {"value": true}
}
```

How do I map it to the following object

```
data class PoJo(val SomeStringProperty: String,//
 val SomeIntProperty: Int,//
 val SomeBooleanProperty: Boolean)
```

Comment: @tynn please tell me how said adapter would look like

Comment: https://medium.com/@int02h/custom-deserialization-with-gson-1bab538c0bfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to register a `TypeAdapterFactory` for all types which might be wrapped. The factory then delegates to the actual adapter. If and only if the json contains a single property named `"value"` it'll provide this property value to the delegate instead.

The implementation should be similar to the following. Here `write` always writes the original value and `read` follows the idea from above.

```
class GenericAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {

    override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, TypeToken<T> type): TypeAdapter<T> {
        val delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type)
        val jsonAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement::class.java)
        return GenericAdapter<T>(delegateAdapter, jsonAdapter)
    }
}

class GenericAdapter<T>(
    private val delegateAdapter: TypeAdapter<T>,
    private val jsonAdapter: TypeAdapter<JsonElement>
) : TypeAdapter<T> {

    override fun read(reader: JsonReader): T {
        if (reader.peek() != BEGIN_OBJECT)
            return delegateAdapter.read(reader)
        var element = jsonAdapter.read(reader)
        element = with(element.asJsonObject) {
            takeIf { element.entrySet().size == 1 }?.get("value")
        } ?: element
        return delegateAdapter.fromJsonTree(element)
    }

    override fun write(writer: JsonWriter, value: T) {
        delegateAdapter.write(writer, value)
    }
}
```